# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Tags: android, leanback

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 это исключение как я понял выпадает когда какие то проблемы с нахождением стиля. Выпадает оно у меня на телике, когда пытаюсь AlertDialog показать

```
<style name="TvAppTheme" parent="Theme.Leanback">
    <item name="browseTitleViewLayout">@layout/view_title</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert</item>
</style>
```

Если использовать тему AppCompat вместо Leanback то все работает, но мне то нужен линбек

Comment: Возможно, вам надо либу `leanback` подключить. Но её подключают по разному при использовании или нет `androidx`

Comment: Спасибо, но такой глупой ошибки у меня нет, что я использую leanback не подключив ее))   Дело в том, что при создании алерта я использовал этот стиль val builder = Builder(context, R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert)   а в теме линбека этого стиля нет наверно, использовал стиль R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert и всё работет, хотя оба стиля находятся в библиотеке поддержки appcompat 1.1.0  я так и не понял точно в чем причина, где чего не хватает, но заработало